# JupyterHub Helm install: function "dig" not defined

Tags: jupyter, kubernetes-helm, jupyterhub

I tried installing JupyterHub 1.0.1 using Helm 3.4.0, but get this error about a dig function.

```
"jupyterhub" already exists with the same configuration, skipping
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "jupyterhub" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈Happy Helming!⎈
Release "jupyterhub" does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: parse error at (jupyterhub/templates/hub/_helpers-passwords.tpl:35): function "dig" not defined
```

Answer (score 7):

The solution is to upgrade Helm. I upgraded to 3.6.2 and don't get the error. I believe dig is a Go template function which does not exist in earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Helm version 3.3 and less, then you might face this issue, as dig tool was added to it later to this version. Try upgrading helm to the latest [version](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases)

Below is the procedure to upgrade helm on LINUX machine

`$ wget https://get.helm.sh/helm-v3.8.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz`

`$ tar -zxvf helm-v3.8.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz`

`$ mv linux-amd64/helm /usr/local/bin/helm`

`$ chmod 700 /usr/local/bin/helm`

`$ exec $SHELL`

`$ helm version`